# Dynamic margin-top in Pdfkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have two different types of headers, one for the first page and other for the other pages. Both have different heights, but I only found ways where I can set only one value for margin-top option using PDFKit/wkhtmltopdf. Thus the same spacing is set on all page headers.

Is there a way where I could set different margin-top value for different pages so my headers can fit in right without leaving empty spaces? I am using Ruby on Rails with PDFKit 0.5.2 and my code currently looks like:

```
# Generate the contents of the PDF and store the file
  PDFKit.configure do |config|
    config.default_options = { :page_size => 'Letter', :margin_top => 75, :margin_left => 2,
      :margin_right => 2, :footer_left =>"(c)",
      :footer_center => "Created on #{Time.now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}",
      :footer_right => '[page] OF [toPage]', :encoding => 'UTF-8', :print_media_type => true }
  end
```

And I serve the html for header from a url and select different header type based on page attribute.

```
<meta content="url" name="pdfkit-header_html">
```